# How to loop xmlnodes in parallel

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel-processing

I have the following code:

```
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
 String NAME = xn["name"].InnerText;
}
```

I want to launch each loop in parallel. How can I do this? I thought that I could use the following method, but I can't figure out the way to make it work:

```
        ParallelOptions parOptions = new ParallelOptions();
        parOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4; //only up to 5 threads allowed.
        Parallel.ForEach(xnList.AsEnumerable(), parOptions, xn=>
        { 
         String NAME = xn["name"].InnerText;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
        var parallelLoop1 = xnList.Count;
        Parallel.For(0, parallelLoop1, index =>
        {
         String NAME = xnList[index]["name"].InnerText;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you tried could be done as below:

```
Parallel.ForEach(xnList.AsEnumerable(),
                 item=>{String NAME = item["name"].InnerText;});
```

But if you using winform and you want to do some processes and preventing from waiting cursor, this is another problem.

Comment: Error 3 'System.Xml.XmlNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable' and the best extension method overload 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: XmlNodeList does not contain AsEnumerable() method.

Answer (score 2):

I found this the link below which allows you to do a foreach in parallel on a non-generic collection like XmlNodeList.

```
// Process the results in parallel
Parallel.ForEach(nodes.Cast<XmlNode>(), options, (thenode) =>
{
    // do stuff
});
```

[Details of parallel foreach over non-generic collections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/03/02/9971804.aspx)